# Python - How to recognize EOL in FASTA file

Tags: python, eol, fasta

I have a python script that needs to read through a FASTA file character-by-character. To do this I have been using `c = f.read(1)`, where f is the opened file. I need it to recognize when it reaches the end of a line, but '\n' and '\r' don't seem to work. I have never worked with this file type before so I'm not sure if FASTA is different. Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks!

Edit: EOF != EOL. I know how to find the end of file.

Edit 2: The line I'm using to search for the EOL character is this:

```
if c == '\n' or c == '\r':
    #operations to perform if found...
```

Comment: Just wondering why you're doing this... you are aware of the myriad of FASTA parsers and supporting libraries out there for this kind of thing, right?

Comment: Yes, but I was told to design a way to do it without any specially built parsers, to design it myself

Comment: Are you opening it in text or binary mode?

Comment: @user2357112 At the moment I have it open in binary, if there's a way to do it in text however I could change it

Comment: I've written parsers for FASTA in Python and it worked fine using the standard line ending characters.  Perhaps you could post some more of your code in case the problem is elsewhere?

Comment: According to [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTA_format) the EOLs are normal and proceed a line with `>` until the next `>` so you can just read lines normally... are you having difficultly identifying the end of the *sequence*?

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz I'll add the line I'm using to the question above

Comment: If you're opening it in binary mode, the line endings may be two characters, `'\r\n'`.

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks for the tip, I just tried adding that into the if statement above, unfortunately no luck :( thanks though

Comment: @thnkwthprtls: Well, of course not, since you're looping character by character. Try opening the file in text mode, which will convert newlines to `'\n'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the file in [universal newline](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) mode:

```
with open('myfile.fasta', 'rU') as fp:
   ...
```

and compare the character against `'\n'`:

```
if c == '\n':
```

Comment: I had never heard of that, but it seems to have worked. Thanks! :)